# Disable External Wester Digital MyBook from spinning Down

Tags: external-hard-drive, power-management

I have this external hard drive for my cloud; and it constantly spins down. I do want it to do so. How do I disable this at the hardware level? I am able to disable this on my seagate drives at the hardware level.